# issue with switch inside a do while, control cannot fall through from one case label to another

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have the following code :

```
        do{

        Console.Write("Please Input a Value: ");
        userInput = Console.ReadLine();

        v = userInput.ToString().Substring(0, 1);
        amount = Convert.ToInt32(userInput.ToString().Substring(1, 1));

        switch(v)
        {
            case "a": mother.incr1(amount);
            case "s": mother.incr10(amount);
            case "d": mother.incr100(amount);
            case "f": mother.incr1000(amount);
            case "=": Console.WriteLine("The total amount is: {0} \n", mother.current);
            case "r": mother.current = 0;
        }

        }while(mother.overflow() != true);
```

when I added the do while, it returned an error "control cannot fall through from one case label #caselabelname# to another" on all the case lines

Comment: maybe you forgot to put "break"s in case statements

Comment: You need to add break statements corresponding each case statement where you do not want the code to fall through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a "break;" between each statement

```
  switch(v) 
    { 
        case "a": 
                mother.incr1(amount); 
                break;
        case "s": 
               mother.incr10(amount); 
               break;
        etc.etc. 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `v` can only be a single character at a time, there is no reason to allow the case to fall through. You should put a `break` at the end of each case.

Answer (score 1):

C# inherited the switch statement from the C language.  Which has case statement fall through, an incredibly fertile source of hard to diagnose bugs.  In your code, fall through will always leave mother.current set to 0.

The C# language *requires* you to terminate a case statement explicitly to avoid this trap.  You must either use *break* to let code resume at the statement following the switch statement.  Or use *goto case* to direct it to resume execution into another case statement.  The *break* keyword is clearly the appropriate choice here.